# Конвертация JSON массива в виде строки в byte[]

Tags: java, json, конвертация, bytearray

Подскажите может есть более лучший способ перегнать такое `"[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, ...]"` в массив байт?

В данном случае в строке в массиве это байты.

В Гугле нашел такое решение:

```
String response = "[-47, 1, 16, 84, 2, 101, 110, 83, 111, 109, 101, 32, 78, 70, 67, 32, 68, 97, 116, 97]"; 

String[] byteValues = response.substring(1, response.length() - 1).split(",");
byte[] bytes = new byte[byteValues.length];

for (int i=0, len=bytes.length; i<len; i++) {
   bytes[i] = Byte.parseByte(byteValues[i].trim());     
}

String str = new String(bytes);
```

Может более лучший способ такое сделать?

Comment: Чем тебе такой способ не подходит?

Comment: @RomanC подходит. но может есть лучше.

Answer (score 6):

Можно использовать Gson для этого

```
byte[] bytes = new Gson().fromJson(response, byte[].class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с использованием [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson):

```
byte[] bytes = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonStr, byte[].class);
```

Вариант с использованием [org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java):

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
byte[] bytes = new byte[jsonArray.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    bytes[i] = Byte.parseByte(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
}
```

Вариант с использованием [javax.json](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/json/package-summary.html) и стримов:

```
try (JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(response))) {
    JsonArray jsonArray = jsonReader.readArray();

    int[] bytes = jsonArray.stream()
                           .map(Objects::toString)
                           .mapToInt(Byte::parseByte)
                           .toArray();
}
```

Правда в этом варианте используются целые числа, так как байтовых стримов не существует и попытки работы с байтами превращаются в костылестроение.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с использованием [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) если response - строка в формате JArray

```
byte[] bytes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<byte[]>(response);
```